# all element of the field is a zero of some polynomial with coefficient in the subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

*Let **S** be a sub-field of **F** satisfying the condition that **F** is finitely generated as a vector space over **S**. For all $f\in F$ show that there exist a nonzero polynomial $P(X)\in S[X]$ satisfying $P(f)=0$.*

The statement is certainly true in the case of **R** and **C**, but how can I show it in general? any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Let $\dim_S(F)=n$, then $1,f,f^2,...,f^n$ are linealy dependent over $S$.